# How to see if a person accepted an invitation in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2003

I've invited some people to a meeting. Therefore an invitation was sent out. Now I want to see which people accepted/declined and so on. I'm using Outlook 2003.

Where do I find a status or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

#### How to Check Responses to Your Meeting Requests in Outlook 2013

Note:

- This also works in older versions of outlook.

> To check the status of responses to your meeting request, follow these
> steps:
>
> 1. Click the Calendar icon in the Navigation bar.
> 2. The calendar appears.
> 3. Double-click the item you want to check.
> 4. The meeting opens.
> 5. Click the Tracking button.
> 6. The list of people you invited appears, listing each person’s response to your invitation.
>
> Note:
>
> Only the meeting organizer can find out who has agreed to attend a
> certain meeting.
>
> [image]

Source [How to Check Responses to Your Meeting Requests in Outlook 2013](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-check-responses-to-your-meeting-requests-in.html)

Comment: There is a neat little trick to this: you can copy this grid to e.g. Excel.